# D3 - set interaction on path stroke (mouseover, contextmenu)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am struggling to select the stroke of each link path correctly. As soon as the mouse is over a path the related stroke turns red. I actually want that the stroke only turns red if the actually stroke receive the mouse over action and not the whole path.

I assume strongly I need to address it differently, like a nested d3.selection to perform the correct task.

The same issue appears for the context menu alert. Currently I can right click at any place on a path and the context menu appears. It should only appear if I right click on the stroke.

I appreciate any hints.

```js
        var width = window.innerWidth,
            height = window.innerHeight;

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        ////////////////////////
        // outer force layout
        
        var data = {
            "nodes": [{
                "id": "A",
            },
            {
                "id": "B",
            },
            {
                "id": "C",
            }],
            "links": [{
                "source": "A",
                "target": "B"
            },
            {
                "source": "B",
                "target": "C"
            },
            {
                "source": "C",
                "target": "A"
            }]
        }

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("size", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-200))
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id
            }).distance(250))

        linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linkscontainer")
        nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")


        links = linksContainer.selectAll(".link")
            .data(data.links)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("fill", "lightgray")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
            .attr("cursor", "pointer")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).attr("stroke", "red")
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).attr("stroke", "black")   
            })
            .on("contextmenu", function(d) {
                alert("ContextMenu selected")
            })

        nodes = nodesContainer.selectAll(".nodes")
            .data(data.nodes, function (d) {
                return d.id;
            })
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "nodes")
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragStarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragEnded)
            )

        nodes.selectAll("circle")
            .data(d => [d])
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", "circle")
            .style("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("r", 40)

        simulation
            .nodes(data.nodes)
            .on("tick", tick)

        simulation
            .force("link")
            .links(data.links)

        function tick() {
            links.attr("d", function (d) {
                var dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x),
                    dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y),
                    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

                return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
            })

            nodes
                .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
        }

        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = null;
            d.fy = null;
        }
```

```css
    .nodes {
        fill: whitesmoke;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
    <!-- D3 -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98a5e27706.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this css rule

```
.link {
        pointer-events: visibleStroke;
}
```

Be aware though that as you zoom out it'll get more and more finicky to select the link -  a lot of d3 graph layouts add fatter "ghost" links that pick up pointer events to compensate for this